# Modifying cell of table view sorted by segmented control edited

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view of tasks. I have also a segmented control above the table that has two choice, the first is for displaying the regular table the other one filters the array of the table to pick the elements that has the same date of the current date and then , I add these new elements to a new array and reload the table view that checks if the selected button in the segmented control is the second one , it will load the elements of filtered array as cells of the table. I have an action on the cell, so if you click them you go to a view where you can change the color of the cell. The problem is happening here. I store the index path of the cell in the table to determine which cell ( row ) is going to be edited, but if the selected segmented button is the second one, the index will be stored according to the order of the element in the filtered table , so when I finish editing the cell, the color will be changed of the cell that has that index not the actual cell because of the conflict between the normal table and the filtered table indexes. Hope that clear enough to explain my case , if it is not, ask me for more explanation.

here is the table loading code :

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if sortTableClicked
    {
        return filteredAchivements.count


    }else
    {

    return achievements.count

    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AchievementsCells
    var arr = [achievement]()
    if sortTableClicked
    {

        arr = filteredAchivements

    }else
    {

        arr = achievements

    }

       cell.name.text = arr[indexPath.row].name

        cell.des.text = arr[indexPath.row].des

        cell.date.text = "\(arr[indexPath.row].date) : تم إضافته بتاريخ "
        cell.backgroundColor = arr[indexPath.row].cellColor

    return cell
}
```

and I have this function that receives the index path sent from the table and apply the changes depending on this index path.

```
    func applyEdit(color: UIColor, name: String, des: String, index: NSIndexPath) {



    taskMgr.editCellDataAtIndex(index, forTable: "achievementsTable", theNewName: name, theNewDes: des, theNewColor: color)


    taskMgr.loadData("achievementsTable")
    achievements = []
    achievements = taskMgr.achievements

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

what happens is that if the loaded table is the filtered one and let's say I want to edit the second cell , the indexpath.row will be 1 , so the changed- color cell will be the second one on the table , but actually the second cell in the filtered table is the fifth one in the non-filtered table , so I want to apply changes on this fifth one not the second one , does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are saving cell index path which is static and is not changing with change in your table view.

You can fix this easily by adding one more `bool` property in your model `arr` that feeds data to table. Name is `shouldChangeColor` and set this property to `true`. Now, your model data is updated. Use this property in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function to change the cell colour.

Since cells are drawn in the order you supply your data from model, this would guarantee that your 2nd cell is painted in colour in filtered mode and 5th in other tab mode.

Comment: Ok i can do that  but the problem is if you press the cell you will be in a new scene where you can change the cell's color and that - as mentioned - depends on the index of the cell, so I used the filtered table and I selected the second cell and I changed its color this cell is the 5th one in the non-filtered table , bu wehen displaying the non-filtered table the second cell will be the cell edited. I need a way to apply the changes according to the cell itself not according to the order of the cell which causes the conflict between the tables' cells.

Comment: I think here you are looking on passing index path of the tapped cell to different view controller which is pretty easy. When you tap on the cell, you can get index path in didSelectRowAtIndex path function which you can save and pass to your new scene in prepareToSegue function.

Comment: That will be mostly the same of what I did, well , you pass this index path to the next when selectin a cell in the filtered table to the next scene and you modify the cell according to this index , so when displaying the non-filtered table , the cell of that index will be the modified one not the actual cell !

Comment: I thought you are changing the cell colour from same view controller but looks like you are changing it from different view controller. My post would work like a charm then also. The only thing you need to ensure is to update the model from second view controller. You can create a protocol and define a method in it. Then set first view controller as delegate to second view  controller. When you want to change the cell colour call that delegate on first view controller. Finally in that delegate, update your model as I said and reload the table. It should work for both your segments.

Comment: Ohhh :/ . I did that exactly , maybe you didn't get my point yet . When I edit that cell in the filtered table i call the function exist in the same view of the table ti reload the table using delegation. The problem in reloading process itself. Suppose I have the following elements in the table: a-b-c and the are all black i have segmented control to sort the elements and filter them ,so it will display the elements that starts in c letter , so the only element in the filtered table will be c , i press c and go to another scene that takes the indexpath of the cell and changes....

Comment: Its color according to its index path, its index is one because it was the only element in the filtered table that sent the index , so swift know that the color of the first element will be changed to red, so i reload the filtered table and i get the red color for cell c which is the only one, also , i reliad the non-filtered table and i am expecting c to be the cell of the color red, but no , the index path passed to function was 1 , so the red color in the non-filtered table will be the red one which is a not c ! And c is black! Because it is not the one that has the index 1 !

Comment: So the qustion is  i want to change the colour of c itself not the color of the first cell in the table, if if c is indeed red in the filtered table , it is not in the non - filtered table. So maybe i have to depend on something rather than index path to change the color of that cell specifically but what is that thing ?!

Comment: Yes, that's what I said - you cannot depend on index path. Update model which is used by cells. You just need to reload the table once model is updated. This will work for filtered data as well. If I had your code I could have fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by updating model? Is it the array of the table view ? I have two arrays one for non-filtered and another for filtered

Comment: Yes - update your non-filtered one and I trust that filtered one is created from non-filtered one so filtered one will also get auto updated.

Comment: I am sorry if I bothered you , ok i will update the non-filtered array , that means i havae to change the color property of that element , but it is still the same problem . How would i know what the index if that element in the non-filtered array i know that it is the indexPath.row in the filtered array , but how would i know which element in the non-filtered array  corresponds this element in this filtered array to apply the same editing and update the proper element in the non-filtered array ??

Comment: Pleeeeease answer me i really need your help : / @Abhinav

Comment: Crux here is - if your model is updated with right data, you can render you table as which way you want. If I would you - I would set the property on model. I would ensure this model object is part of my non-filtered array. That said, I would ensure my filtered array is generated out of non-filtered array. So, essentially, both filtered and non-filtered arrays contains the updated model object. I think do no need to depend on the cell index at all. Because I have my model updated at the right index in the array. All I would then do is reload my table view. Hope this makes sense to you!

Comment: I have non filterd array of the struct ( item ) that has the property ( color ) and filterde array that is of the same struct. Non filterd contains [ a , b , c ] filterd contains [ c ] i loaded the filtered one and change the color prperty of c in the filtered on and i want to apply the same changes on the non filtered one. So i need to update it as you said . Although the filtered array is generated by by calling the function filter for non filtered one , the update you make in the first will not autmatically applied on the other one! Because arrays are by value. Just tell me....

Comment: What do you mean by updating the non filtered one ? Do u mean that i change the property color of c element in the filtered array and reload the table and that will be applied on the non filtered one ?! How would that work . Just give me a simple example of two arrays that one of them is generated by another and you update an element in both in the same time using the code if u can ://

Comment: I under stand your point that i can update the property in the non filtered array and regenerate the filtered array again so it will work. But that drives me the same problem, i choose the element to be the edited one from the filtered array so i know where this element in the filtered array but I don't know where it is int non-filtered array, i cannot edit it in the filtered one and regenerate the first one ( non-filtered) because the second one is generated by the first one not the opposite thing. Once i know the order of the element c in the first array by clicking it in the second array ..

Comment: I can then apply what you suggested, other wise i cannot do it. Because as I mentioned the the second array can be updated according to the update if the first one because it is part of it, whereas the first one cannot be updated according to updating the second array because it is the origin of the second not part of it

Comment: Try this out - 1) add a property called ID on your model. 2) create a dictionary with key as ID and value as 0 or 1 based on cell should highlight or not. 3) keep this dictionary along with your filtered and non-filtered arrays. 4) fetch object from your filtered array that needs to be coloured. 5) update dictionary using ID of filtered array. 6) in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` use this dictionary only for cell colouring - use object ID and fetch whether to colour or not. Hope this would fix your issue. Accept this answer if it does; I've spent good amount of time on this ;-) ... Good luck!

Comment: No i am sorry maybe I didn't get your point. If you have a patience to continue please write a simple code, or don't continue and that is enough from u , u did your best thank u :)

Comment: Ahhh... I am sorry. See point is you need a way where both your filtered and non-filtered arrays are in sync. That is the key. If you are able to achieve that - you will win the battle. When I say in sync I mean that colour flag value. So, as an alternate, you can have a handshaker between your two arrays - a dictionary. This dictionary will have key as an ID which is common in both the arrays so both these arrays can access dictionary using key. Value in dictionary is important for you which is nothing but colour flag (0 or 1). All you need is now, set correct value in dict and then fetch it.

Comment: Aha i got it. I made the dictionary wich is the common side between the two arrays. And the dictinary have the key of 0 or 1 , so once i changed the color of c element in the second array i changed the property id and i changed the key of the dictionary depending on this. In cell for row at index path, i fetched the value of the dictionary that if it is 1 the id of the first array will be true and the cell will be colored. But what i get now is cells and all of the are colored because the value of the key of the dictionary is alawys 1 in all cells of the non filtered table , so what to do now?